# @Media Screen query working on inspect but not working on actual devices

Tags: html, css, ios, media-queries, screen

I've created a website in which I used @media screen to make sure the elements sit right on smaller screens. While creating this website, I used the toggle device toolbar feature on google chrome to manage my elements on different screen sizes. Everything looked good and so I published my website; the problem is multiple elements have shifted around and no longer look good on smaller viewport sizes. Also, my chosen fonts disappear when the website is visited on smaller screens but work perfectly fine on a desktop.

[image]
[image]

(Top one is a screenshot of website through the toggle device toolbar on desktop and the bottom one is a screenshot of the website on my actual phone)

[image]
[image]

(Same as above)

I'm also missing some images when i visit the website on my iPad. I thought maybe I missed something in my original file, however, everything seems to be working fine. When I use the toggle device toolbar on a laptop, everything's in place; however, when I actually look at the website through my phone everything is different. Im really lost on what to do. Any advice is appreciated.

Ive already added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">` to all of my HTML files

and this how i've set up all of my queries

```
/* Iphone 12 pro, Iphone Xr, Iphone X */

@media screen and (max-width: 390px)  {
   .girl {
     background-image: url(Images/Iphone12pro.gif);
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 150%;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   margin-top: 0%;
   z-index: 8000;
cursor: url(Cursors/3.png), auto;
 }
}
```

Comment: can you try to change the max-width value from 390px tp 420px? As some devices may have a screen width greater than 390px that's why most probably the styling of the desktop will be reflected.

Comment: Try to create a small example which we can run to see the problem for ourselves. It doesn't have to include all your code, just something that goes wrong on actual smaller devices. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: @SurajSanwal Unfortunately, the code I posted is only a snippet. I have multiple media queries for different screen sizes; 6 to be precise.

Comment: @98SSVM So, Have you checked on other devices? Is it now working any of them? or just for Iphone 12 pro, Iphone Xr, Iphone X ?

Comment: @AHaworth I've looked into doing this but my website contains animated pngs which aren't supported on imgur; I won't be able to show the problem to the fullest because of this. Not sure if this will help but i can share the link to the github files: https://github.com/Ayanfe-Digital/Ayanfe-Digital.github.io.git

Comment: @SurajSanwal Yes, I've checked on an Ipad and the problem persists there too

Comment: It might be an issue with the way you are using the media queries. Can you just do a check is the media querries closed correctly. It's looks like your css file not well formatted and you missed to close your ver first media query for ipad  on your style.css file on the github repo shared above

Comment: @SurajSanwal I've taken your advice and fixed the formatting but it hasn't changed anything. The issue seems to be with the text aspect of the website. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention 'animated pngs' (not sure what these are) - are you saying the problem is only to do with those? If not, create an example of one of the other problems for us to see. And are you absolutely sure your code is fully validated correct HTML and CSS?